# JQuery: How can I change property with addClass when stylesheet selector is more specific?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

By some stylesheet, a tag is specifically selected and styled.
By adding a class with JQuery, i would like to override one property. However, the stylesheet selector is more specific, so the property from the added class is not effective. How can I adjust the property with JQuery in this case?

In the snippet, the red text should change to blue. But it stays red.

It should be solved with `addClass`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p:first").addClass("hero");
    });
});
```

```css
p:nth-of-type(1) {
    color: red;
}

.intro {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: red;
}

.hero {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Add a class name to the first p element</button>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/ .css("color", "red") for example

Comment: If possible, using `addClass`

Comment: Define p.hero instead of .hero for css rule.

Comment: If it's a requirement that the styles can't be changed (because they are not under your control), then please make that very explicit in the question.

Comment: Is it possible, that the the class attribute stub `class=""` needs to be present in the markup, for JQuery to be able to set it?

Comment: As stated already, and if to be able to alter the CSS, the proper way would be to change the rule to `p.hero { color: blue; }`, and if you can change it, do that instead of `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Just added `:not(.hero)` to the `p:nth-of-type(1)` line did the job for me!

That way, you'll be setting the red color only if the first p do not have the class hero

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p:first").addClass("hero");
    });
});
```

```css
p:nth-of-type(1):not(.hero) {
    color: red;
}

.intro {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: red;
}

.hero {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Add a class name to the first p element</button>
```

Comment: The first stylesheet selector is given. It has to go through `addClass` in JQuery

Comment: In my example, the red color will be applied to the first p, but only if this p does not have the hero class, when I click the button, it will addClass("hero") to the first p. Doing so, color: red will not be applied because the p is using hero class. 

I'm not sure I understand what's your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not access to `css` file,  add new `.hero` style inside of  your `html` like this:

```
 <style>
     .hero { color: blue !important; }
 </style>
```

---

But, if you have not access to `html` too, try this to add above style dynamically (add this to your `document.ready`):

```
 var stEl = document.createElement('style'); 
 document.head.appendChild(stEl); 
 stEl.sheet.insertRule(".hero { color: blue !important; }", 0);
```

Comment: I think he can only use JavaScript, not modify the CSS.

Comment: No need to modify css. He can add new `style` tag to his `html` separately. Check my updated answer for its descriptions.

Comment: There's supposed to be a solution with `addClass`

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` in the css declaration and then apply it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p:first").addClass("hero");
    });
});
```

```css
p:nth-of-type(1) {
    color: red;
}

.intro {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: red;
}

.hero {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Add a class name to the first p element</button>
```